# ${p^k \choose n}\equiv pa'(-1)^{a-1}\,\pmod {p^2}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $0\leq n \leq p^k$. Prove that

$${p^k \choose n}\equiv
\begin{cases}
1\,\pmod {p^2}   & \text{if $n=0$ or $n=p^k$} \\[2ex]
pa'(-1)^{a-1}\,(mod\, p^2) & \text{if $n=ap^{k-1}$, $1\leq a\leq p-1$, $aa'\equiv1\pmod {p}$}  \\[2ex]
0\,\pmod {p^2} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I know that ${p^k \choose n}=\frac{p^k(p^k-1)...(n+1)}{(p^k-n)!}$
I stuck here:
If ${p^k \choose n}\not\equiv 0$ then $p^{k-1}|(p^k-n)!$, in this condition how can i prove that ${p^k \choose n}\equiv pa'(-1)^{a-1}\,\pmod {p^2}$ for $n=ap^{k-1}$, $1\leq a\leq p-1$, $aa'\equiv1\pmod {p}$ ?

Can somebody give me some hints?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I started working on this but it took me more time than I hoped for. I did not reach a conclusion but hopefully this might be of some help, or else someone might find some mistake I made here.

---

When $n=ap^{k-1}$ we have that:

$$\binom{p^k}{n}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{\big(p^{k-1}(p-a)\big)!}}_{\text{(F)}}\cdot\underbrace{\prod_{l=0}^{p-(a+1)}\,\,\prod_{i=1}^{p^{k-1}}\,(a+l)p^{k-1}+i}_\text{(P)}$$

How many factors $p$ show up in the product $P$?
For a term in the product to be divisible by $p$, $i$ must be a multiple of $p$ between $1$ and $p^{k-1}$.

### Case $(1)$: $i<p^{k-1}$

Then $i$ must be of the form $\sum_{1\leq j < k-1} a_jp^{j}$, where $0\leq a_j \leq p-1$, except that at least one $a_j$ must be nonzero.
And how many factors does this yield?
Each such term yields a number of factors equal to $j_{\min}$, where $j_{\min}$ is the smallest $1\leq j<k-1$ for which $a_j$ is nonzero.

For each $j=1,2,\dots,k-2$, how many terms in the product have $j_{\min}=j$? One may choose between $p-1$ options for $a_j$ ($0$ is excluded), and $p$ options for $a_m$, $j<m<k-1$. This gives a total of $(p-1)\cdot p^{(k-1)-j-1}$ possible terms, and hence the number of $p$ factors from $i$ is

$$\sum_{1\leq j<k-1}j\cdot(p-1)p^{k-j-2}$$

Now, let us not forget that these $p$ factors occur for each of the $p-a$ values of $l$. It follows that the total number of factors for this case

$$(p-a)\cdot\left(\sum_{1\leq j<k-1}j\cdot(p-1)p^{k-j-2}\right)$$

### Case $(2)$: $i=p^{k-1}$

Then the term in the product is of the form $\big((a+1)+l\big)p^{k-1}$, so that when $0\leq l<p-(a+1)$, the term contributes with $k-1$ factors and and when $l=p-(a+1)$ it contributes with $k$ factors, for a total of $(k-1)\cdot\big(p-(a+1)\big)+k=(k-1)(p-a)+1$ factors.

### Total

$$(p-a)\cdot\left((k-1)+\sum_{1\leq j<k-1}j\cdot(p-1)p^{k-j-2}\right)+1$$

---

Now, how many factors $p$ are there in the factorial $F$?
Only multiples of $p$ between $1$ and $p^k-ap^{k-1}$ contribute with factors.
How many such multiples are there?
Any such number will be of the form $p^k-ap^{k-1}-i$, where $0\leq i < p^{k-1}(p-a)$ and $i$ itself is a multiple of $p$.

Hence, $i$ must be of the form $\sum_{1\leq j \leq k-1} a_jp^{j}$, where $0\leq a_j\leq p-1$ for $1\leq j <k-1$ and  $0\leq a_{k-1}< p-a$.
Once again, how many factors does this yield?

We make an analysis similar to the one above.
For each $j=1,2,\dots,k-2$, one may choose between $p-1$ options for $a_j$, $p$ options for $a_m$ with $j<m<k-1$ and $p-a$ options for $a_{k-1}$.
For $j=k-1$, there are simply $p-a-1$ options.
Hence, the total is

$$p-(a+1) + \sum_{1\leq j <k-1}j\cdot (p-1)p^{k-j-2}(p-a)=\\(p-a)\cdot\left(1+\sum_{1\leq j <k-1}j\cdot (p-1)p^{k-j-2}\right)-1$$

---

### Difference

The number of $p$ factors that $P$ has more than $F$ is

$$(p-a)(k-2)+2$$

so $\binom{p^k}{n}$ should be a multiple of $p^{(p-a)(k-2)+2}$, which looks quite wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I think it has a short answer.